# Attach arbitrary data to Highcharts data points

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to attach additional data to a data point, and later access that data directly from an event handler?

```
series: [{
    data: [
        { x: ..., y: ..., customProperty:... }
    ]
}]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JGCmt/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to access the date from an event handler.

```
event.point.options.customProperty
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/maheshsapkal/JGCmt/2/)**